# Python: Why will assignment of new column in new dataframe appear in the preceding dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I ran the following codes and I'm confused with the assignment logic. In the example, I randomly set the 1st dataframe and pulled the table. On the 2nd line of code, I tried assigning the original dataframe to the 2nd dataframe and worked with it by adding additional column. When I pulled the 1st dataframe again (df1), it's showing the added column. Can anyone assist to explain this?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAJC9.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @Cmingy! You should look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) to produce reproducible problems!

Comment: You should never describe code but show it.

Answer (score 1):

You just gave the same Dataframe two names with `df2 = df1`. Assignment **never** copies data. You can issue `df2 = df1.copy()`.